# Can diffusion produce energy?

Tags: energy, diffusion

A friend and I recently got into a silly argument where I stated

> pure diffusion can't produce energy since **diffusion are a part of passive transport**.

He stated if we

> If we have tinny turbine which allow to transfer only one molecule at a time due to the different concentration the molecule will make turbine rotate and produce energy (which I thought this assembly will be a non-permeable since direct  contact is must in diffusion )

On the other hand we encounter some research trying to produce energy by differentiating level of water separated by a semi-permeable. And they accomplish producing energy how that happen (I think they give an energy in another way by differentiating concentration and they collect this energy. It is only an engineering)

Comment: Energy can (in everyday settings) be neither produced nor destroyed, it is [conserved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy). Perhaps you'd like to peruse Wikipedia a bit and then come back and reword your question?

Comment: what I mean is using diffusion as source of energy.Is that possible? since it is passive transport I think it is not.

Comment: Does compressed gas moving through a small hole into a bigger chamber counts as diffusion? If so, putting a turbine there will certainly produce energy

Comment: a hole that allow only one molecule at a time and this turbine closes the hole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you mean by diffusion.

If you're considering a system at equilibrium, e.g. a sodium chloride solution, and you're trying to extract energy from the diffusional motion of the sodium and chlorine atoms then you can't extract any energy. Your friends idea of a tiny turbine is effectively the same as the [Maxwell's demon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell's_demon) idea for extracting energy from the thermal motion of gas molecules.

On the other hand, if you're considering a non-equilibrium system, e.g. where there is a concentration gradient, of a solute then yes you can extract energy from this. The easiest way would be to use a semipermeable membrane as you describe.

[image: SPM]

If your semipermeable membrane allows solvent through but not the solute, then there will be a net flow of solvent from the low concentration to high concentration side. This creates an [osmotic pressure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmotic_pressure) so there is a force on the membrane, $F$. Allow the membrane to move a distance $x$ and you can extract some work $W = Fx$.

Comment: where does this energy come from ? since we count diffusion as  passive transport. in a closed system how does you mention on osmatic pressure since there needs to be equilibrium. if there is an force on membrane than there should be some negative energy

Comment: @HalisYılboğa: suppose you had gas on one side and a vaccum on the other. You wouldn't be surprised that there was a pressure on the membrane. Because the concentration of the solute is higher on one side in effect its pressure is higher on that side.

Comment: your sample is not in equilibrium in term of pressure. initially if there were a balance this balance can't break by diffusion IMHO. please enlight me.

Comment: @HalisYılboğa: yes, if the system is initially at equilibrium diffusion isn't going to make it move to a higher energy state.

Comment: then there is no way to produce energy using only diffusion.

Comment: @HalisYılboğa: no, not unless the diffusing system is not at equilibrium

Answer (score 0):

If there is a concentration difference in a closed system then from that difference, energy can be extracted. And the sum of the energy extracted would be equal to the energy that made the system imbalance in the first place.

For example suppose there is a room full of Nitrogen and Oxygen molecules and there is a membrane dividing the room letting Nitrogen molecules to pass but not letting the Oxygen molecules. Somehow i brought an Oxygen magnet and managed to pull all the Oxygen molecules to one side of the room. If i let go the Oxygen molecules, then the Oxygen molecules will want to go back to the other side of the room, too, to make it equilibrium again, that is called diffusion. Suppose i have tiny Oxygen turbines, then i could regain the energy while the diffusion occurs. And the amount of that energy would be equal to the energy i input to make it imbalance initially.

An implementation example of this concept could be read here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmotic_power